# {Python} How can I convert dictionary into Coordinates?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, coordinates

```
{1: [0, 0], 2: [1, 0], 3: [2, 0], 4: [3, 0], 5: [4, 0], 6: [5, 0], 7: [5, 1], 8: [5, 2], 9: [5, 3], 17: [4, 4], 28: [3, 4], 29: [2, 4], 30: [1, 4], 31: [1, 3], 32: [1, 2], 33: [2, 2], 34: [3, 2], 35: [3,0: [5, 4], 11: [5, 5], 12: [4, 5], 13: [3, 5], 14: [2, 5], 15: [1, 5], 16: [0, 5], 17: [0, 4], 18: [0, 3], 19: [0, 2], 20: [0, 1], 21: [1, 1], 22: [2, 1], 23: [3, 1], 24: [4, 1], 25: [4, 2], 26: [4, 3], 27: [4, 4], 28: [3, 4], 29: [2, 4], 30: [1, 4], 31: [1, 3], 32: [1, 2], 33: [2, 2], 34: [3, 2], 35: [3, 3], 36: [2, 3]}
```

I have a dictionary like above, the front numbers are values and the latter(list) are coordiates,
How can I print the dictionary to coordinates?

This is sprial array by the way.

(sorry for the bad English.)

I think it is better to explain in picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1kRp.jpg)

Comment: @TJCWorld no, I want to print something like this
               .
               .            
............   9
...........    8
...........    7
1 2 3 4 5 6

sprial numbers.

for example, 1 is in (0,0,)
                     2 is in (1,0)

Comment: @TJCWorld sorry for the confusing comment it is my first time using stackoverflow. I explained it through image. Thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to fix up your dictionary (`d`) a bit, I think 10 got dropped.

```
coords = np.array(list(d.values()))
out = np.zeros(coords.max(0) + 1)
out[tuple(coords.T)] = list(d.keys())

out
Out[]: 
array([[ 1., 20., 19., 18., 17., 16.],
       [ 2., 21., 32., 31., 30., 15.],
       [ 3., 22., 33., 36., 29., 14.],
       [ 4., 23., 34., 35., 28., 13.],
       [ 5., 24., 25., 26., 27., 12.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.,  9.,  0., 11.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean plotting coordinates on a Cartesian axis:

```
coords = list(dict.values())

x = np.array(coords)[:, 0]
y = np.array(coords)[:, 1]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

If you just want to print the coordinates:

```
print(dict.values())
```

Comment: sorry for vague expression in the original question. I've added a picture to help you understand easier. Thank you.